# Variation of boundary action

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, boundary-conditions, variational-principle, cosmological-inflation

How does varying the boundary action

$$S = \int_{t_0} d^3 x \sqrt{g}\left(-{\textstyle\frac12}\kappa\phi^2\right)\tag{5}$$

eq. 5 of of https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0503458, lead to

$$\partial_n \phi = - \kappa \phi\tag{7}$$

eq. 7 of the same paper?

Answer (score 0):

The equation (7) does not follow directly only from (5), but also from the terms which you find by varying the bulk action and transfering them to the boundary by partial integration.

The complete action for a scalar inflaton field would have to be (as seen in [1] which OP's mentioned paper cites)
\begin{equation}
S =\int \sqrt{g} \,d^{3} x d t \Big(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_{\mu} \phi\right)^{2}-\frac{m^{2}}{2} \phi^{2}-V(\phi)\Big) + \int d^3x\,\sqrt{\tilde{g}}\Big(-\frac 1 2 \kappa \phi^2\Big)
\end{equation}
If we vary wrt. $\phi$ we get
\begin{equation}
\delta S = \int \sqrt{g} \,d^{3} x d t \Big((\Box - m^2- \frac{\partial{V}}{\partial\phi})\delta\phi  - \partial^\mu(\delta\phi\partial_\mu\phi) \Big) + \int d^3x\,\sqrt{\tilde{g}}\Big(-\kappa \phi \delta \phi\Big)
\end{equation}
Due to the determinant being covariantly conserved, partial integration is easy.
Now, examine only the term
$$
-\int \sqrt{g} \,d^{3} x d t\, \partial^\mu(\delta\phi\partial_\mu\phi) = -\int \sqrt{g} \,d^{3} x d t\, \partial^n(\delta\phi\partial_n\phi) - \int \sqrt{g} \,d^{3} x d t\, \partial^i(\delta\phi\partial_i\phi)
$$
In this example the index $n$ could be replaced by the time index, but in more generality, it is the direction orthogonal to the spacelike surface. The second term on the RHS above we discard as it can be related to a surface integral at spatial infinity where we still assume variations vanish, but the first one is kept, and can be related to a surface integral on the spacelike slice
$$-\int \sqrt{g} \,d^{3} x d t\, \partial^n(\delta\phi\partial_n\phi) = -\int \sqrt{\tilde{g}} \,d^{3} x(\delta\phi\partial_n\phi)$$

Now we can collect all terms in $\delta S$ which are evaluated on the boundary

$$\delta S_B = -\int \sqrt{\tilde{g}} \,d^{3} x(\partial_n\phi + \kappa\phi)\delta\phi $$

from which the required equation (7) follows

[1] K.Schalm, G.Shiu and J.P.van der Schaar, arXiv:hep-th/0401164